# Python convert list of IPs inrange of IPs into dash

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, range, ip

Given list of IPs

```
list_of_ips = ['10.0.0.10', '10.0.0.11', '10.0.0.12', '10.0.0.13', '10.0.0.40', '10.0.0.43', '10.0.0.44', '10.0.0.45', '10.0.0.46', '10.0.0.47', '10.0.0.48', '10.0.0.49', '10.0.0.50', '10.0.0.51', '10.0.0.52', '10.0.0.53', '10.0.0.54', '10.0.0.55', '10.0.0.56', '10.0.0.57', '10.0.0.58', '10.0.0.59', '10.0.0.60']
```

Want to collapse the list into range of IPs with dash if sequence of IPs in range or single IP.

Example:

```
output = ['10.0.0.10-10.0.0.13', '10.0.0.40', '10.0.0.43-10.0.0.60']
```

Here is the partially working code, for some reason I can't get the last range after `10.0.0.43 - 10.0.0.60`

Not sure were why it is not adding

```
def compare_ips(ip1, ip2):
    last_octet1 = int(ip1.split('.')[-1]) # splits the ip and grabs the last octet
    last_octet2 = int(ip2.split('.')[-1]) # splits the ip and grabs the last octet
    if last_octet1 > last_octet2:
        return -1
    if last_octet1 < last_octet2:
        if (last_octet2 - last_octet1) == 1:
            return 1
        else:
            print("More then 1")
            return 99
    return 0

range, group = [], []
for a, b in zip(list_of_ips, list_of_ips[1:]):
    check = compare_ips(a, b)
    if check == 1:
        group.append(a)
        continue
    elif check == 99:
        if not a in group:
            check2 = compare_ips(a, b)
            if check2 == 1:
                group.append(a)
                continue
            else:
                group.append(a)
        if not b in range:
            range.append(b)
        if len(group) > 1:
            range.append("{}-{}".format(group[0],group[-1]))
            group = []
```

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `netaddr` module for this:

```
pip install netaddr
```

https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_01.html#list-operations

```
list_of_ips = ['10.0.0.10', '10.0.0.11', '10.0.0.12', '10.0.0.13', '10.0.0.40', '10.0.0.43', '10.0.0.44', '10.0.0.45', '10.0.0.46', '10.0.0.47', '10.0.0.48', '10.0.0.49', '10.0.0.50', '10.0.0.51', '10.0.0.52', '10.0.0.53', '10.0.0.54', '10.0.0.55', '10.0.0.56', '10.0.0.57', '10.0.0.58', '10.0.0.59', '10.0.0.60']

merged_list = netaddr.cidr_merge(list_of_ips)
print(merged_list)

[IPNetwork('10.0.0.10/31'),
 IPNetwork('10.0.0.12/31'),
 IPNetwork('10.0.0.40/32'),
 IPNetwork('10.0.0.43/32'),
 IPNetwork('10.0.0.44/30'),
 IPNetwork('10.0.0.48/29'),
 IPNetwork('10.0.0.56/30'),
 IPNetwork('10.0.0.60/32')]
```

Now, if you want to verify whether your result is correct you can do:

```
import ipaddress
[str(ip) for y in merged_list for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network(y)]

#output
['10.0.0.10',
 '10.0.0.11',
 '10.0.0.12',
 '10.0.0.13',
 '10.0.0.40',
 '10.0.0.43',
 '10.0.0.44',
 '10.0.0.45',
 '10.0.0.46',
 '10.0.0.47',
 '10.0.0.48',
 '10.0.0.49',
 '10.0.0.50',
 '10.0.0.51',
 '10.0.0.52',
 '10.0.0.53',
 '10.0.0.54',
 '10.0.0.55',
 '10.0.0.56',
 '10.0.0.57',
 '10.0.0.58',
 '10.0.0.59',
 '10.0.0.60']
```

Comment: thank you, that's not what I'm looking for. I have collected all the ips from the subnet. Instead of having long list of IPs, wanted to add range of IPs list.

Comment: I have added the partially working code, can't get the last range working.

Answer (score 0):

`netaddr` doesn't offer exactly what you need but not much code is needed to achieve that:

```py
from netaddr import cidr_merge, IPRange

def merge_ranges(ranges):
    """Yield the ranges with adjacent input ranges merged together."""
    if len(ranges) == 0:
        return

    ranges = sorted(ranges)
    (current, *rest) = ranges
    for r in rest:
        if r.first == current.last + 1:
            current = IPRange(current.first, r.last)
        else:
            yield current
            current = r
    yield current


list_of_ips = [
    '10.0.0.10',
    '10.0.0.11',
    '10.0.0.12',
    '10.0.0.13',
    '10.0.0.40',
    '10.0.0.43',
    '10.0.0.44',
    '10.0.0.45',
    '10.0.0.46',
    '10.0.0.47',
    '10.0.0.48',
    '10.0.0.49',
    '10.0.0.50',
    '10.0.0.51',
    '10.0.0.52',
    '10.0.0.53',
    '10.0.0.54',
    '10.0.0.55',
    '10.0.0.56',
    '10.0.0.57',
    '10.0.0.58',
    '10.0.0.59',
    '10.0.0.60',
]

networks = cidr_merge(list_of_ips)
ranges = [IPRange(n.first, n.last) for n in networks]
merged = list(merge_ranges(ranges))
print(merged)
assert merged == [
    IPRange('10.0.0.10', '10.0.0.13'),
    IPRange('10.0.0.40', '10.0.0.40'),
    IPRange('10.0.0.43', '10.0.0.60'),
]
```

The output:

```
[IPRange('10.0.0.10', '10.0.0.13'), IPRange('10.0.0.40', '10.0.0.40'), IPRange('10.0.0.43', '10.0.0.60')]
```

which you can now format and present however you want, I left that part out.

I'll think about adding something like this `merge_ranges` to `netaddr`, seems reasonably useful.